# Why does Instagram's pagination return the same page over and over?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, pagination, instagram

## **The Code**

I've created a PHP class to communicate with Instagram's API. I am using a private function called `api_request` (shown below) to communicate with Instagram's API:

```
private function api_request( $request = null ) {

    if ( is_null( $request ) ) {
        $request = $this->request["httpRequest"];
    }
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $request, array(
                "timeout" => 10,
                "content-type" => "application/json"
            )
        )
    );

    try {
        $response = json_decode( $body, true );
        $this->data["pagination"] = $response["pagination"]["next_url"];
        $this->data["response"] = $response["data"];

        $this->setup_data( $this->data );

    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        $this->data = null;
    }
}
```

These two lines of code...

```
$this->data["pagination"] = $response["pagination"]["next_url"];
$this->data["response"] = $response["data"];
```

...sets up my data within this array:

```
private $data = array (
    "response"      => null,
    "pagination"    => null,
    "photos"        => array()
);
```

## **The Problem**

Whenever I request the next page, with the following function:

```
public function pagination_query() {
    $this->api_request( $this->data["pagination"] );
    $output = json_encode( $this->data["photos"] );

    return $output;
}
```

Instagram gives me the first page, over and over and over gain. 
Any idea what the problem is here?

## **Update #1**

I realized that because my `setup_data` function (used in `api_request` function) pushes my photo objects onto the end of my `$this->data["photos"]` array:

```
private function setup_data( $data ) {

    foreach ( $data["response"] as $obj ) {

        /* code that parses the api, goes here */


        /* pushes new object onto photo stack */
        array_push( $this->data["photos"], $new_obj );
    }
}
```

...it is necessary to create an empty array, when requesting a new page:

```
public function pagination_query() {

    $this->data["photos"] = array(); // kicks out old photo objects

    $this->api_request( $this->data["pagination"] );
    $output = json_encode( $this->data["photos"] );

    return $output;
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the second page but all subsequent `pagination_query` calls only return the second page. Any ideas what could be wrong?

## **Update #2**

I discovered that using a `while` statement, to make the `api_request` function call itself, allows to me retrieve page after page just fine:

```
private function api_request( $request = null ) {

    if ( is_null( $request ) ) {
        $request = $this->request["httpRequest"];
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $request, array(
                "timeout" => 18,
                "content-type" => "application/json"
            )
        )
    );

    try {
        $response = json_decode( $body, true );

        $this->data["response"] = $response["data"];
        $this->data["next_page"] = $response["pagination"]["next_url"];

        $this->setup_data( $this->data );

        // while state returns page after page just fine
        while ( count( $this->data["photos"] ) < 80 ) {
            $this-> api_request( $this->data["next_page"] );
        }

    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        $this->data = null;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't fix my `pagination_query` function and it appears as if my `try-catch` block is creating a closure and I'm not really sure what to make of this.

Comment: what is the output of the `$response` array

Comment: Hi @MichaelStClair you can find the structure of the response  envelope here: [Instagram API Endpoints](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Comment: print out `$response["pagination"]["next_url"];` and see if there is even a value there

Comment: @MichaelStClair I suspected that as well but it returns the pagination.next_url parameter from the json, as expected.

Comment: do you need the `$this->` in front of it to assign that value to the array? What happens if you remove that?

Comment: `$this->` is a reference to the current object. If I remove it, will look for another variable of the same name (but not find it).

Answer (score 2):

In your first snippet of code you have:

```
    $this->data["response"] = $response["data"];
    $this->data["next_page"] = $response["pagination"]["next_url"];
```

Note two keys: `response` and `next_page`

Then in your second snippet you have:

```
    $this->data["pagination"] = $response["pagination"]["next_url"];
    $this->data["response"] = $response["data"];
```

Now `next_page` is `pagination`

Now if you use

```
$this->api_request( $this->data["pagination"] );
```

But you are using  `$this->data["next_page"] = $response["pagination"]["next_url"];` of course you will not get the right results.

In any case try to var_dump the content of of your $request:

```
public function pagination_query() {
    var_dump($this->data["pagination"]);
    $this->api_request( $this->data["pagination"] );
    $output = json_encode( $this->data["photos"] );

    return $output;
}
```

If you have a debbugger also check inside api_request which is the url passed each time

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the name of the key for clarity and forgot to update it in my question (Sorry about that). In regards to the `var dump`, I changed the `return` in my `pagination_query` function to `return $this->data["next_page"]` and it returns the link to the second page over and over again. The only question I'm trying to figure out is why all subsequent `pagination_query` calls return the link from the very first time it was called?

Comment: Do you think something, within my `try-catch` block, would cause the variables to persist or not update?

Comment: yes if sonething goes wrong in the try...catch you won't get the next_url correctly

Comment: must be add a url for reference api

Comment: hey @rubenrp81, could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following lines of code to the `try` block of my `try...catch` statement to return several successive pages at a time:

```
while ( count( $this->data["photos"] ) < 160 ) {
    $this-> api_request( $this->data["next_page"] );
}
```

This essentially tells `api_request` to call itself until my `$this->data["next_page"]` array is populated with 160 "grams."

This allows me retrieve a total of 320 grams from Instagram's api: 160 grams when `api_request` is called after page load and another 160 from my first `pagination_query` call.

This isn't an ideal solution as a second `pagination_query` call **still** returns the same data from my first `pagination_query` call but it will have to do for the time being.

## **Update**

The above solution is a hack. If anyone can figure out why my `pagination_query` method still isn't working, it would be much appreciated.